# Where does check_mk store configuration files?

Tags: ubuntu, nagios, check-mk

I'm a little new to the check_mk/nagios/monitoring world. I'm experimenting with omd 1.0 as an easy way to get it all set up and working on an Ubuntu host. So far, things are great!

With all the work I'm putting in to the system though, I thought a backup would be a good idea. Traditionally, it seems that host and check configurations were saved in the main.mk file for check.mk, but mine shows:

```
# Put your host names here
# all_hosts = [ 'localhost' ]
all_hosts = [ ]
```

Well... that's not interesting! I have about 40 servers/switches added and showing in check_mk multisite.

I'm using WATO for check_mk to add hosts, and I'm guessing that's why things aren't written to that file. I would like to continue managing with WATO for simplicity.

So - where are host and check information written?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WATO, you might need to check the following directories -

```
/etc/check_mk/conf.d/wato/
```

you will find `hosts.mk` in the above directories.

```
/etc/check_mk/multisite.d/wato/
```

Comment: Bingo! Just needed to dig a bit deeper into the folders. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for clarification of any other Open Monitoring users who are looking - things are in /opt/omd/(your site) - and then the paths above

Answer (score 0):

As for backups, a good way is to download your last changes' snapshot from WATO, in the backup & restore menu.
(Depends on the use case, sometimes I'll also go with *omd backup* or *cmk --backup*)

If doing it all manually, please also grab var/check_mk/autochecks (inventory state) and local/share/check_mk/checks (custom checks you added).